# Rendering HTML emails with inline CSS using Jinja

Tags: html-email, template-engine, jinja2

As you know, if you are going to send an HTML email, all CSS styling must be inline on the elements themselves e.g. `<p style='font-family: Helvetica'>`

Is there a way I can use Jinja to easily create HTML email bodies from Jinja templates without repeating CSS styles many times in a single template?

I think of setting these styles to variables e.g.

```
{% set FONT_STYLE = 'font-family: Helvetica; color: #111' %}
```

and then in the template I can do

```
<p style='{{ FONT_STYLE }}'>My paragraph here.</p>
```

Any better ideas? Maybe a library that resolves CSS rules that takes HTML content and CSS file and binds calculated CSS rules to the HTML elements one by one?

Comment: How did you solve this issue by using premailer. I don't get, how can I use the 'transform' function in a jinja2 template. Please let me know the way you have solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [`premailer`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer/) which turns CSS blocks into style attributes. You can get pretty html and convert it to email html with `premailer`.